# How to rate-limit the API requests to x per second?

Tags: android, rx-java2

My app is making repeat API requests to download chunks of data. Unfortunately the server limits the API requests to 3 per second. **In the code below, how can I rate limit the requests to X per second ?**

```
private void getHistoricalPrices(String currency, String start_date, String end_date, int granularity){
    // show download status
    currentDlPageIndex++;
    view.showDownloadingStatus(currentDlPageIndex, totalDlPages);

    // make the API call
    addDisposable(
            model.isNetworkAvailable()
                    .doOnSuccess(isNetworkAvailable -> {
                        if (!isNetworkAvailable) {
                            showErrorMessage();
                            Timber.v("no internet");
                        }
                    })
                    .filter(isNetworkAvailable -> true)
                    .flatMapSingle(isNetworkAvailable -> model.getHistoricalPrices(currency, start_date, end_date, String.valueOf(granularity)))
                    .subscribeOn(rxSchedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(rxSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe((Response<List<List<String>>> responseData) -> {
                        if (responseData != null && responseData.code() == HTTP_OK) {
                            List<List<String>> response = responseData.body();

                            if (response != null) {

                                // create list from downloaded data
                                ArrayList<HistoricPrice> tmpHistoricPriceList = new ArrayList<>(response.size());
                                for (List<String> rawHistoricPrice : response) {
                                    HistoricPrice historicPrice = new HistoricPrice(rawHistoricPrice.get(0), rawHistoricPrice.get(1), rawHistoricPrice.get(2), rawHistoricPrice.get(3), rawHistoricPrice.get(4), rawHistoricPrice.get(5));
                                    tmpHistoricPriceList.add(0, historicPrice);
                                }

                                // add the downloaded list to the main list being recreated
                                model.historicPriceList.addAll(tmpHistoricPriceList);
                                Timber.d("added %d records to memory", response.size());

                                // if there's more to download, download another chunk
                                if (intermediateDateSecs != null && intermediateDateSecs < endDateSecs){
                                    startDateSecs = tmpHistoricPriceList.get(tmpHistoricPriceList.size()-1).time + granularity;// add "granularity" to startDateSecs to avoid getting two exact data for the same time
                                    Date startDate = new Date(startDateSecs * 1000L);//requires milliseconds, not epoch
                                    String startStrDate = DateUtils.fromDateToString(startDate);

                                    intermediateDateSecs = startDateSecs + ((ApiService.MAX_HISTORIC_RETURN_VALUES - 1) * granularity);
                                    if (intermediateDateSecs > endDateSecs) intermediateDateSecs = endDateSecs;

                                    Date intermediateDate = new Date(intermediateDateSecs * 1000L);
                                    String intermediateStrDate = DateUtils.fromDateToString(intermediateDate);

                                    getHistoricalPrices(currency, startStrDate, intermediateStrDate, granularity);
                                } else {
                                    // no more to download, save data
                                    Timber.d("downloaded total of %d records", model.historicPriceList.size());
                                    view.hideDownloadingStatus();
                                    showSaveDataMessage();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, error -> {
                        showErrorMessage();
                    })
    );
}
```

you can see that the method `getHistoricalPrices()` calls itself to continue downloading. This implementation works well, except for the server complaining when there's too many API requests per second.

Comment: I think I found a solution: replace the `.observeOn(rxSchedulers.mainThread())` with `.delay(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, rxSchedulers.mainThread())`. the 300ms guarantees there's no way the server can complain about too many requests per second, but in practice there's 100ms to 200ms delay already built in per call just waiting for a response from the server.
I'll use this delay implementation for now, unless someone has a better approach ?

Comment: hard-coding a delay like that basically assumes the device has excellent connectivity and slows it down. However, it doesn't account for slower network conditions - in this case it just slows it down even more. It would be much better to have a dynamic delay

Comment: `.delay` only delays the emissions. So if the source emits 100 items seconds, the resulting observable will also emit 100 items per seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform your request every X milliseconds / seconds like so:

```java
long interval = 0L; // Your desired interval here in milliseconds
Observable.interval(0, interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .takeUntil(x -> isTaskComplete == true)
    // Other configuration calls go here
    .subscribe(); // make request here or in doOnNext()
```

Comment: I'll try it. I will try: calculate ms between now and previous API call. Update `interval` to give enough delay for next API call.